# Getting a value form JSON and Store in a variable

Tags: javascript, json

Hi i am new to development i have below JSON object kindly help me out to fetch the value and store in another variable:

```
{
    "testData1": "testResukt1",
    "testdat2": "testResulrt2"
}
```

Kidly help me out how to fetch the value of testData1 and store in ler var1;

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Please take a [tour] and visit [ask]. This site is explicitly for Salesforce related questions. Your question is a simple Javascript question that might already have answers in stackoverflow. This [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) should help you understand how to parse the JSON and get the required values into a variable.

Comment: The best place to get started with core syntax and logic is Trailhead, or in the case of pure JavaScript, a resource such as the Mozilla Developer Network.

Answer (score 4):

If it's in the context of JavaScript,

```
let jsonString = '{"testData1": "testResukt1", "testdat2": "testResulrt2"}';
let data = JSON.parse(jsonString);
let var1 = data.testData1;
```

If it's in the context of Apex, you can define an Apex class and then deserialize the JSON string into the class. Then `testData1` is just a property of the class;

```
public class TestData {
    public String testData1 {get; set;}
    public String testDat2 {get; set;}
}

TestData data = (TestData) JSON.deserialize(jsonString, TestData.class);
String var1 = data.testData1;
```

Or you can simply deserialize the JSON string into a map using the `deserializeUntyped` method:

```
Map<String, Object> m = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonString);
String var1 = (String) m.get('testData1');
```

Answer (score 1):

First there is not `ler` in javascript. I believe you are new to `JS` so please kindly go through tutorials to familiarize yourself with basics of `JS`.

For your answer, you can store them as below :

```
let var1 = JSON.parse('{"testData1": "testResukt1","testdat2": "testResulrt2"}').testData1.
```

Every JSON string can be parsed as object in `JS`. So when you use `JSON.parse` your JSON string acts as an object. From that object you can access the property of that using `.`propertyName as shown above.